# ASP.NET Mvc Url Action Pass to Main Root From Admin Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

Now, i edit some pages on **Admin Area** on my ASP.NET MVC Project.
How link go to Front End ?

```html
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Front End</a></li>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add routeValue area in order to change it. So if you want to go to your main area you have to use something like this:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })
```